# mysql2 0.4.0 ruby gem require error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mysql2

I installed **mysql2** gem using command: gem install mysql2

```
Done installing documentation for mysql2 after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

But when I do `require 'mysql2'`, I get:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2
```

Even though the gem installed successfully, `gem list mysql2`

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

mysql2 (0.4.0)
```

I am using MacOSX with `ruby 2.1.5p273`

Any suggestions as to where should I be looking ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have quoted gem name like this `require 'mysql2'`? Please, show your script.

**UPDATE**: Looks like a [bug](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/675) in `mysql2-0.4.0` version.

If you don't need exactly this version (I doubt so), just rollback to previous latest stable release in `0.3.x` branch:

```
ruby-2.1.5 in ~/projects › gem install mysql2 -v '~> 0.3.0'
Fetching: mysql2-0.3.20.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.20
1 gem installed
ruby-2.1.5 in ~/projects › irb
>> require 'mysql2'
=> true
>>
```

Comment: Just did that in Irb:
and installed this version 0.3.0:
Still getting... 
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2

from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'

from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'...

from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'

Comment: This is really strange, because I have exactly the same environment and all's working fine. Try removing other versions of `mysql2`: `gem uninstall mysql2`

Comment: Thanks, for the prompt reply, had uninstalled the previous version of mysql2. But didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using platform -

```
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby
```